# Is it possible to use common principal components for assessing covariance matrix similarity in R? 

Tags: r, pca, ecology

Is it possible to use common principal components for assessing covariance matrix similarity in R?

This approach was championed by Flurry, 1988 but [this paper](http://people.biology.ufl.edu/osenberg/papers/2006mccoy-oecologia.pdf) is what I have in mind.

#### References

- Flury B (1988) Common principal components and related multivariate models. Wiley, New York

Comment: Could you give the full reference of Flurry 1988?

Comment: Sure it is a book Flury B (1988) Common principal components and related multivariate models. Wiley, New York

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand, but the paper you link to has an R package that implements CPCA in R as used in the paper. Ben Bolker contributes here but IIRC he has moved from Florida now so the web link in the paper is dead. Ben is now at McMaster and you can find the latest version of that package here: http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/R/ look for the `/bin` folder for compiled binary or `/src` for the sources (for use on Linux).

Comment: Yes, yes there is Ben Bolker package but it seems that the maintenance had ceased so maybe there is some other solution. I am having trouble with running this on newer R versions, because of the namespace issues. Maybe I could re-use this code, but maybe someone did it before me?

Comment: I would contact Ben directly. He is a very friendly chap and offers his R packages in multiple forms so may be able to compile the source into a binary using a newer R if that is a problem. Anyway, Ben is the best person to help so drop him an email.

Comment: I contacted Ben and got the package working. But it is still using old Phillips` CPC program as an internal .exe. This makes it very very very slow, and it can only deal with up to 20 characters. So the search continues. Any other such packages?